# Нельзя исправить вопрос из-за превышения лимита на тело вопроса

Tags: дефект, правки, редактор

Вопрос, который я хотел отредактировать не поддался на сохранение, так как был превышен лимит. Как его вообще тогда создали?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: [Определять выход дочернего элемента за границы родителя? js (jquery)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074091/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-js-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

У меня есть целый [большой ответ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316084/4928642) про это, но в данном случае ответ куда проще - писать меньше пробелов:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Как его создали?

Comment: @СвободуСергеюСуровцеву а вы уверены, что там действительно превышен лимит, может это был одноразовый глюк? По моим подсчетам 26846 символов

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight несколько раз пробовал.

Comment: @СвободуСергеюСуровцеву, там нет 30К. Скорее всего их добавляет твоя правка каким-то образом.

Comment: @Qwertiy я воспользовался кнопкой **привести в порядок**.

Comment: @СвободуСергеюСуровцеву, ну вот оно и отформатировалось, добавив уйму пробелов. Там же css минифицированный.